# How do I set up a Log for my Backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, servlets, backend

**I am using Android Studio 2.3.2 & Google Cloud Platform (App Engine).**

**The following picture is from a Servet.java class**

[image]

**As we can see in the picture, Toast is not recognized on the module Backend, it just says add library... and it doesn't work at all**
[image]

**because on the Gradle -Backend- it doesn't add any other library, Gradle -Project- just have gradle stuff.**

**Well, the Sout... (System.out.println) where should be expected? on the Android Monitor? I already used every category combinatorially using the regex and it doesn't show up. (I tried with the regex off)**

[image]

**then I check up the App Engine from Google Cloud Platform and it doesn't seems to be any kind of Log. (sorry for the spanish mix on it)**

[image]

**I will appreciate any tip for debugging, or setting up any kind of log on Android Studio or Google Cloud Platform to check the Sout or any other possible log.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's stopping you from adding the imports to the gradle file?

Comment: A) Which Gradle File are you talking about? I got 1) Project, 2) App, 3) Backend.

B) Which kind of imports? Toast? I just clicked the Imports for the Toast and Android Studio seems to not be working at all while adding them. In other words I click 'Add' and nothing happens.